# French visa processing location and public holidays

Tags: visas, schengen, france, schengen-visas, pakistan

Is a passport sent to France for visa processing or is it processed at the local embassy (applicant's home country) for a French visa? Do public holidays in my home country have an impact on visa processing time? Will decision be delayed by holidays?

Comment: Where is your home country?

Comment: @traveller It's pakistan(I applied on french embassy in islamabad ,pakistan) and there are 5 holidays comming next week in islmabad,pakistan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is a passport sent to France for visa processing or is it processed at the local embassy (applicant's home country) for a French visa?

Your passport is not sent to France; it is held at the Embassy.

> [6.How will I get my passport back after Biometrics/Interview?](http://www.aegfrenchvisa.com.pk/Default.aspx?PageID=10)
>   Upon interview, passport is retained by the French Embassy for processing. It is generally sent back to concerned visa center after minimum 02 weeks time. On receipt of passport, applicants will be notified for collection through our call centre within 24 Hours.

In Pakistan, [AEG Travel Services (Pvt) Ltd](http://www.aegfrenchvisa.com.pk/Default.aspx?PageID=11) manages all appointments to submit visa applications on ordinary passports.

> Do public holidays in my home country have an impact on visa processing time? Will decision be delayed by holidays?

National holidays do affect times at the visa service provider and the Embassy's Consular services (as well as French national closures).

> [Opening Hours of Embassy- Consular Office](http://www.aegfrenchvisa.com.pk/Default.aspx?PageID=8)
>  
>   All appointments to submit applications are to be made through AEG, appointments will take place from Monday to Friday, 9:00 AM to 1:00 PM and during the month of Ramadan from Monday to Friday, 9:00 AM to 12:00 PM.
>
> All appointments to process biometric details will be awarded through AEG and will take place at the Embassy from Monday to Thursday, 9:00 AM to 12.30 PM.
>
> Please note return of passports is also handled through AEG Travel Services (Pvt) Ltd.
>
> Office Timings ::: Monday to Saturday ::: 9:00 AM 5:00 PM 
>   Lunch Break :::  1:00 PM 2:00 PM 
>   Friday (Lunch & Prayer Break) ::: 12:30 PM  2:30 PM 
>   Closed on Sundays & National Holidays
>
> Office Timings During Ramadan  ::: Monday to Thursday ::: 8:30 AM 2:00 PM 
>   Friday & Saturday ::: 8:30 AM 12:30 PM 
>   Closed on Sundays & National Holidays